# Como converter um JSONArray em um array de Strings?

Tags: java, json, array, split

```
 String mensao = "[\"brega_falcao\",\"SamiPietikainen\",\"TecRahul\",\"gpantuza\",\"mkyong\",\"mkyong\",\"YouTube\"]";
```

Mensao é o JSONArray  que quero converter.

Tentei isso mas não funcionou:

```
//Retiro o '[' do inicio e do fim ']' do array json 
    String modificada = mensao.substring(1, mensao.length() - 1);


        List<String> lista = Arrays.asList(modificada);
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + lista.get(i));
        }
```

O problema é que ele imprime uma string  grandona e não criar um array de strings...(foi isso que eu mandamos o codigo fazer , ma não é o que queremos...)

Saida

```
0 "brega_falcao","SamiPietikainen","TecRahul","gpantuza","mkyong","mkyong","YouTube"
```

Enquanto o desejado é isso:

```
0 brega_falcao
1 SamiPietikainen
2 TecRahul
3 gpantuza
4 mkyong
5 mkyong
6 YouTube
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa separar a *String* maior em *Strings* menores pelo separador (",") antes de passá-la para o `Arrays.asList(...)` utilizando o método `split(String)`. Além disso, deve remover as aspas:

```
String mensao = "[\"brega_falcao\",\"SamiPietikainen\",\"TecRahul\",\"gpantuza\",\"mkyong\",\"mkyong\",\"YouTube\"]";
String modificada = mensao.substring(1, mensao.length() - 1);

Arrays.stream(modificada.split(","))
        .map(s -> s.substring(1, s.length() - 1))
        .foreach(System.out::println);
```

Para coletar a `Stream` como um `array`, você pode utilizar o método `toArray`. Exemplo:

```
String[] strings = Arrays.stream(modificada.split(","))
                         .map(s -> s.substring(1, s.length() - 1))
                         .toArray(String[]::new);
```

**Uma observação importante**: esse método funciona para o caso exemplificado por você, porém não funcionará adequadamente caso suas *Strings* contenham vírgulas ou caso hajam espaços próximo as vírgulas. Caso você precise levar esses problemas em conta, será necessário uma outra solução, como através do uso de expressões regulares.

Comment: Obrigado, mas como posso retornar um Array de String ao invés de imprimir, podeira adicionar mais essa função  a sua resposta?

Comment: @PenaPintada Quando você fala "array", você diz realmente um `array` ou uma lista (como no exemplo da sua pergunta)?

Comment: String[] mensao = new String[tamanho];

Comment: @PenaPintada Adicionado na resposta.